# Suppose $f\in H(U), f(U) \subseteq U$. How many zeros can $f$ have in the disc $D(0,\beta)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve exercise 9 from chapter 15 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis:

> Suppose $0 < \alpha < 1, 0 < \beta < 1, f\in H(U), f(U) \subseteq U, f(0) = \alpha$. How many zeros can $f$ have in the disc $D(0,\beta)$? What is the answer if $f(\alpha)=1/2,\beta=1/2$.

$U$ is the unit disc.

My thoughts:

This sounds like a combination of Jensen's formula and Schwarz lemma but I'm unable to combine them to produce a useful inequality. I would appreciate help. By the way, this is self study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z_1, \dotsc, z_m$ be all the zeroes of $f$ (with multiplicity) such that $|z_k| \leq \beta$ for $k \in \{1, \dotsc, m\}$ and define

$$
g(z) = \prod_{k=1}^m \frac{z-z_k}{1-\overline{z}_k z}.
$$

Then $g(z)$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $\overline{U}$ and $|g(z)|=1$ for all $z$ such that $|z|=1$.
The quotient $f(z)/g(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$ and by the maximum principle $|f(z)/g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in U$. In particular for $z=0$ this results in

$$
1 \geq \left| \frac{f(0)}{g(0)} \right| = \frac{\alpha}{\prod_{k=1}^m |z_k|} \geq \frac{\alpha}{\beta^m}.
$$

So $\beta^m \geq \alpha$ and therefore the number of roots $m$ is bounded by

$$
m \leq \frac{\log(\alpha)}{\log(\beta)}.
$$

For $\alpha = \beta = \tfrac{1}{2}$ you get $m \leq 1$.